# Storage large number of xml documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to storage a large quantity of xml documents in AWS. The projection is about 1,000~3,000/day (700,000/year) with a minimum storage of 5 years. The medium size of this xml documents is around 10 KB so I will take 7 GB of data/year.

This files are generated one by one but the demand to access them is low as it's a legal requirement and the business information will already be in the database.

This files have an internal unique key (44 numeric characters) composed of legal rules and it's secure to save the files with a name based on this key.

The S3 looks a good option due the costs but I will deal with a lot of extra file identifications.

The EBS is more traditional and I could work with a simple folder structure (per client) and store the files with a easy recovery way even in bunch files.

Another option, the EFS, looks promising to but I don't have experience with AWS so I would appreciate the opinion of the community.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think you would need "extra file identifications" if you used S3? I think S3 is an absolutely perfect fit for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the amount of data you have (7GB) just use S3. Don't bother with glacier.

Also for this kind of data volume is totally feasible to keep it all cached on a machine and sync it with S3 periodically (i.e. you can put it in whatever directory structure you want and use s3cmd for example in a simple cron job). It should be good enough and allow you to recover in case the machine fails.

If security of the data is a concern do use s3 client side encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The EBS and Elastic File System approach is mainly for file system based and frequent access based use cases - they are relatively much more expensive than the S3.

I would like to recommend the approach of S3 + Amazon Glacier. You can conveniently  make use of life cycle rules to seamlessly move the data from S3 to Glacier.

The cost of glacier is almost 1 cent per GB per month - but you need to understand that the retrieval process would like 4 to 6 hours.

With S3 and glacier approach - you never would run out of space or need to worry about the scalability aspect - unlike the EBS or EFS where you need to manage the EC2 instances to access / store the data.

Comment: If this is for legal purposes you may also want to look at Glacier Vault Lock which will prevent modifications of files: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/glacier-vault-lock/